# Days Until Christmas Application Java Value Will Not Round Up

Tags: java

I'm teaching myself Java and I am working on this application that will count the days until Christmas. The `HOUR_OF_DAY`, `MONTH`, and `SECOND` values of the `GregorianCalendar` and `Date` objects for today and Christmas are all set to zero. By debugging I can see the variable for the difference in days in milliseconds and it gives me a time of 1641599724 milliseconds which comes out to be 18.99999 days but it wont round up to 19 no matter what I try!

I have tried Math.ceil method to try and round up but I can't get it to equal 19.

**FIRST: DataUtils class stores/modifies input from the user**

```
package chapter13datesstrings;


import java.util.*;

public class DateUtils {

static final int MILLS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

public static Date getCurrentDate(){
    GregorianCalendar currentDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    currentDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return currentDate.getTime();              
}

public static Date createDate(int year, int month, int day){
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    return date.getTime();
}

public static Date stripTime(Date date){
    GregorianCalendar noTimeDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    noTimeDate.setTime(date);
    noTimeDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    noTimeDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    noTimeDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return noTimeDate.getTime();
}

public static double daysDiff(Date date1, Date date2){

    date1 = stripTime(date1);
    date2 = stripTime(date2);

   long longDate1 = date1.getTime();
   long longDate2 = date2.getTime();

   long longDiff = longDate2 - longDate1;

   return (int) (Math.ceil(longDiff / MILLS_IN_DAY));
}    


}
```

**SECOND: DateUtilExample class provides input to the DataUtils class**

```
package chapter13datesstrings;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateUtilExample {


public void thisIsCode(){

GregorianCalendar currentGC = new GregorianCalendar();
int currentYear = currentGC.get(Calendar.YEAR); //sets current year

Date currentDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDate(); //create current date object
Date christmas = DateUtils.createDate(currentYear, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25); //set christmas date
int daysToChristmas = DateUtils.daysDiff(currentDate, christmas); // days until christmas

DateFormat date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(Calendar.LONG);
String formattedToday = date.format(currentDate);

/**** Output Items *****/
System.out.println("Today is " + formattedToday);
System.out.println("Number of Days 'Till Xmas: " + daysToChristmas + " days");
}


}
```

**MAIN METHOD CLASS**

```
package chapter13datesstrings;


import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;


public class Chapter13DatesStrings {

public static void theDates(){
    DateUtilExample dateUtilExample = new DateUtilExample();
    dateUtilExample.thisIsCode();
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
 theDates();
}

}
```

Comment: FYI, while I understand you are practicing to learn Java, you should also know that in the real world the java.util.Date/.Calendar classes should be avoided as they are troublesome, confusing, and flawed. For real work, use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or java.time. Example code in Joda-Time 2.6: `DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
        DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
        DateTime then = new DateTime( 2014 , 12 , 25 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zone );
        int daysUntilXmas = Days.daysBetween( now , then ).getDays();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you divide two integers in Java, the result is rounded down ("truncated") automatically.

The expression `longDiff / MILLS_IN_DAY` isn't equal to `18.99999`, it is equal to `18`.  Java essentially calculates `18.99999` and then throws everything after the decimal point away, *before* you can do anything with it.  Rounding up with `ceil` won't help at that point, because you just end up calculating `ceil(18)` which is just `18`.

One solution to this is to cast the numbers to `double` before you divide them.  `double`'s are floating point values, so dividing them does not round the result down.  To use doubles, replace

```
longDiff / MILLS_IN_DAY
```

with

```
((double)longDiff) / ((double)MILLS_IN_DAY)
```

Another solution, which may be more computationally efficient but a little bit less elegant is to simply add `1` to the result.  This isn't strictly equivalent, because when you are within a millisecond of midnight the result will be a day more than you expected, but this is essentially unnoticeable.  To take this approach, you would replace the line:

```
return (int) (Math.ceil(longDiff / MILLS_IN_DAY));
```

with

```
return longDiff / MILLS_IN_DAY + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what SelectricSimian said,
this is something that can be done in a couple of lines using the [Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) provided by java.
To simply get the day difference between the current time and a given day, you can use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDaysUntil(Calendar.DECEMBER, 25) + " day(s).");
    // If the date is December 25th, this will output "365 day(s)"
    // If the date is December 24th, this will output "1 day(s)"
}

public static int getDaysUntil(int month, int day) {
    /**
     * First get a properly formatted calendar representing right now. This
     * should include leap years and local. With this calendar, we get the
     * day of the year.
     */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    /**
     * Now change the day and month of the current calendar to the given day
     * and month.
     */
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    int desiredDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    /**
     * Then we just get the difference between now and then.
     */
    int difference = desiredDay - today;

    /**
     * If the desiredDay has passed already, or it's currently the
     * desiredDay, we need to recalculate the difference.
     */
    if (difference <= 0) {
        /**
         * We start by getting the days until the end of the year.
         */
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        int daysUntilEnd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - today;

        /**
         * Then, move the calendar forward a year and get the day of year
         * for the desired day again. We recalculate the number of days just
         * in case next year is a leap year.
         */
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        desiredDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        /**
         * Finally, just add daysUntilEnd and desiredDay to get the updated
         * difference.
         */
        difference = daysUntilEnd + desiredDay;
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Definitely an easier way to go with this. I think the book I was reading was just trying to capture multiple things at once, but I like your way of doing this.

Comment: @user3386635 The less code that's necessary, the easier it is to read and understand in my opinion. Also, reusing the standard API's  is a good practice. 
I updated my answer to be more generic about the days as well as take into account if the day has already passed.